# What are the details of .com file format?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I have been given an assignment to make a 2 pass assembler for `8086`. I wish to keep things simple and only assemble small programs for now. I found that the `.COM` format is very simple. However I cannot find the specifics of the file format.

Also I read that execution always begins at `100h`. So won't it be a problem if `MS-DOS`(actually `DOSBOX` in my case) has system programs already present there? And Do I need to provide some default stub code in the `0h`-`100h` part?

I simply want to know how will I write a `.COM` file that is runnable on `DOSBOX`.

Comment: Byte 0 of the com file is loaded to 0x100. The operating system fills 0-0x100 before it (e.g. with the command line arguments and some informational and system structures). Read about segments in x86 real mode.

Comment: Note that .COM files must be a bit smaller than 64 KiB to work properly. If your file isn't then behaviour differs among DOS versions, some will refuse to load the file and others may load it regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.COM` format has no structure, it's a flat binary.

The program (the whole file) is loaded to address `100h` in some segment.  Below that, you'll find the PSP for your program.  The last usable word in the segment (usually at offset `fffeh`) will be overwritten with `0000h` and the stack pointer pointed to it.  This allows you to exit the program with a `ret` instruction.

DOS's program-loader sets all of `CS`, `DS`, `ES`, and `SS` to the segment of your program.  Then, the DOS kernel jumps to address `0100h` (i.e. the start of your program) to run it.  (Technically, the program loader doesn't set `cs` until it does a far `jmp` or `iret` to the `cs:100h`; if it had set `CS` earlier, any `IP` value would be inside the new program's memory, not the DOS kernel.)

That's really all there is to it.  Your program doesn't have to care about segmentation at all, as long as the flat 64K of the "tiny" memory model is sufficient for all your static code+data loaded from the file, stack at the top, and any memory in between as BSS or "heap".  Any segment base works the same, so for example `[bx]` and `[bp]` address the same linear address even though `bp` implies `ss:` and `bx` implies `ds:`.

Note that because the DOS kernel picks a segment for your program, it won't collide with any already loaded programs or the DOS kernel. It'll just work as expected.

As for writing COM programs, I recommend using an assembler like NASM with output format “binary” (i.e. no output format).  The general template is this:

```
        org     100h            # Tell NASM that the binary is loaded to 100h

start:  ...                     # the program starts here.  This must
                                # be the first thing in the file.

        # place any variables or constants after the code
```

Then assemble with

```
nasm -f binary -o program.com program.asm
```

For more information, [this resource](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/829-program_startup___exit.html) might be helpful to you.

Comment: I cannot use NASM. The assignment is to write a simple assembler. So the COM file will be the output of my program(the assembler). I wanted to clarify if loading of the program and starting execution at 100h will be handled by DOS or not? I mean will DOS understand COM extension and do those itself or do I have to do something...

Comment: Does the programmer need to set CS, DS, ES and SS in the beginning of the assembly code or does the OS do that?

Comment: @MahekShamsukha The OS does that for you.  You can completely ignore the segment registers if you don't plan to access memory outside of these 64 kB.

Comment: @MahekShamsukha And yes, DOS /starting with DOS 2, before that, `COMMAND.COM` handled this) is capable of loading programs on its own.  Simply place them in files with the file extension `.COM` or `.EXE` and it just works.

Comment: One last thing... How should the file end?  That is; if I have opened a file and written the machine instructions and data, should I just close the file or should I write some random bytes to fill the rest of the segment? And Thanks for all the help

Comment: @MahekShamsukha Just end the file.  The remaining memory in the segment will not be touched, so it'll be filled with random data from previous programs.

Comment: @MahekShamsukha: `.com` files can be tiny; back in the early DOS days with small floppies, it would have been a disaster if a `.com` file had to be about 64kiB to have bytes in the file for every byte of the 64k segment.

Comment: “_…will DOS understand COM extension…?_”, technically it’s not about the extension. Regardless of whether the extension is EXE or COM, DOS always looks at the first two bytes of the file. If they match the magic signature values “MZ” (4D 5A) the file will be parsed like an EXE (and fail to load if it doesn’t conform to the file format). Otherwise it will be loaded as a flat binary COM file. But everybody keeps the extension consistent so please use the .COM extension; trying to be too clever with that will only make your instructor angry.

Comment: To be explicit, the file contains nothing for the first FFh bytes. DOS fills in those bytes at load time with run-time information. The first byte of your file will be loaded at CS:100h, the second at CS:101h, etc. That’s it.

Comment: @EuroMicelli That is not correct.  The file starts with the first byte of your program which are meaningful and can be anything you want.  The PSP of 256 bytes (not 255 bytes) is prepended at runtime and is not part of the file.

Comment: I think you misunderstand each other, whether it is left free or left out, and are both correct (except 255 vs. 256).

Comment: @fuz, we are saying the same thing. In full: no valid x86 instruction starts with 4D 5A, nor is 4D alone a valid instruction (not in the 8086/8088, and Intel agreed not to, pragmatically wouldn’t, or technically couldn’t, add one such in the future). Since the first byte(s) on a COM program must be a valid instruction (the first instruction to be executed), no valid COM program could possibly start with those two bytes (and yes they are included, loaded at 100h and 101h). Why MZ was chosen is easy to look up. I disagree about the PSP size though: the PSP is definitely 255 bytes long, not 256.

Comment: @EuroMicelli `4D 5A` is `DEC BP; POP BX`.  These are valid instructions, but they are unlikely to appear in the beginning of a program.  But no you are wrong, the PSP is 256 bytes long.  It goes from `00h` to `ffh` i.e. from 0 to 255 which is 256 bytes in total.

Comment: @fuz I stand corrected on both accounts. I forgot to count the zero address, and so it is 256 bytes. And I should have verified the instructions; on that I’ve been embarrassingly wrong for over 30 years. Thank you for setting me straight.